# Electron require module that requires a module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have a very basic function I am trying to figure out but may not be setting this up correctly.

In my main.js, I am requiring a JS file that has a function in it. This function is esentially just trying to access a global variable that was set from main.js

It appears though that the hotkeys.js doesn't have access to the require that is being added? Maybe I am approaching this incorrectly.

I am just trying to separate some logic and I am trying to run the `loadHotkeys()` function thats being included, however that function needs to access a global variable and it appears `remote` is not being included correctly?

```
// main.js
const hotkeys = require('./assets/hotkeys');
global.debug = true;

...

// Load our hotkeys
hotkeys.loadHotkeys();






// hotkeys.js
let remote = require('electron').remote;

module.exports = {
    loadHotkeys: (doReload) => { loadHotkeys(doReload) }
}

/**
 * API call to the hotkeys endpoint.
 * Using the environment username,
 * make a GET call to the Hotkeys endpoint.
 */
function loadHotkeys(doReload) {

    // If we are debugging, use a local JSON file so we don't need to connect to the server.
    if (remote.getGlobal('debug')) {
        // Cannot read property 'getGlobal' of undefined
    }

}
```